# Error on Django Form Wizard - Resets to wizard to step 0 with no data on submit

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm using the django form wizard and its sporadically will reset the wizard to step 0 after submitting the form on the last step.

This only happens very occasionally, and there doesnt appear to be any pattern to indicate why this happens.

Can anyone suggest a possible cause or way to investigate this?  Frankly i'm not sure where to start to investigate this.

thanks

Comment: Show code of your done() function

Answer (score 0):

check if you have any global variable that someone else, on another browser, is resetting